# Typescript testing in Jasmine in Visual Studio environment

Tags: unit-testing, angular, typescript, visual-studio-2015, jasmine

I have looked for three days straight now, and I have great problems finding a good guide to this setup:

**Goal**: Unit testing of functions created by developers in our team.

Solution uses Visual Studio 2015 (+ Resharper).

Solution contains Web project, which is an Angular2 based website, with code written in *typescript*. This typescript is what is supposed to be unit tested.

**What I managed to do**: Set up Jasmine as separate project in the solution. It works, I can create tests that test themselves (*expect(7+1).toBe(8)* kind of thing).

**What I failed to do**: Set up Jasmine to be able to compile *.ts* stuff on the fly (I guess?), to be able to reference *.ts* files and test them.

TL;DR: I need help setting up a Visual Studio project, in an already existing Angular2 solution, that will allow me to use Jasmine to unit test typescript files. (Perhaps someone has run across a guide that would help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to rectify my issue by redefining what I needed.

I installed karma & jasmine in the root app project (where the .ts-es are). Then used webpack to package those .ts-es along with tests (also written in TypeScript).

I used this guide:
http://ericnish.io/blog/set-up-jasmine-and-karma-for-angularjs/

Then this one:
https://templecoding.com/blog/2016/02/02/how-to-setup-testing-using-typescript-mocha-chai-sinon-karma-and-webpack/

The biggest issue was the webpack, but I have also got it to work.